# Parse.Cloud.httpRequest not returning response

Tags: parsing, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to make a Parse.Cloud.httpRequest call, the job executes successfully but i am not getting any response. If i run the request on a RestClient it executes fine but for some reason it's not working in Parse Cloud Code. What am i doing wrong?

```
Parse.Cloud.job("Loader", function(request, status) {

var xmlreader = require('cloud/xmlreader.js');
var moment  = require('cloud/moment.js');

var query = new Parse.Query("Codes");
query.each(function(a) {
  var curDateMonth = moment().date();
  var curMonth = moment().add(1, 'months').month();
  var curYear = moment().year();

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'https://.....'
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
  console.log(httpResponse.text); 
}, function(httpResponse) {
  console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
});

}).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
status.success("Saved successfully.");
}, function(error) {
// Set the job's error status
status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest() is an asynchronous function call. It doesn't block the thread, so your code keeps running to `status.success("Saved successfully.");` before you get the result from httpRequest().

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest() returns a Promise now, so you can simply chain them together.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("Loader", function(request, status) {
    var xmlreader = require('cloud/xmlreader.js');
    var moment  = require('cloud/moment.js');

    var query = new Parse.Query("Codes");
    query.each(function(a) {
        var curDateMonth = moment().date();
        var curMonth = moment().add(1, 'months').month();
        var curYear = moment().year();

        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: 'https://.....'
        });
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse.text); 
        status.success("Saved successfully. httpResponse: " + httpResponse.text);
    }, function(error) {
        // Set the job's error status
        status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
    });
});
```

**Edit**

`each()` is something different, so please add the success callback to httpRequest directly.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("Loader", function(request, status) {
    var allHttpResponseTexts = '';

    var query = new Parse.Query("Codes");
    query.each(function(a) {
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: 'http://example.com',
            success: function(httpResponse) {
                // Process httpResponse.text here

                allHttpResponseTexts += httpResponse.text.substr(0, 50);
            }
        });
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        status.success("Saved successfully. allHttpResponseTexts: " + allHttpResponseTexts);
    }, function(error) {
        status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong. " + error.code + ' - ' + error.message);
    });
});
```

And the final result is:

> Saved successfully. allHttpResponseTexts: <!doctype html> <html>
>   <head> <title>Example D...

Comment: iForests, thank you for the response, when i run the above code i am getting the following error "Failed with: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined"

Comment: Can you provide the detail code of your `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest`? I didn't finish the url part in my code.

Comment: return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: 'https://api.stats.co.za/json'
        });

Comment: Its a GET call request that i am making

Comment: First of all, you should remove the semicolon after the url. And I didn't notice that it's a each() call. For each() call, the then() get called when all each() promises are done. Please see my edit, it's a complete workable example.